How to load items to ComboBox when scrolling to the end
I am populating a ComboBox from an API. The API returns paginated data and there could be 100s of records. I dont want to load on the records at once so I want to load let's say 25 records then when the user scrolls to the end of the ComboBox load the next 25 and so on. The poblem I am having is that I cannot detect the scroll even and call the api for the next set of records. Here is what I've tried so far.
ComboBox
                <ComboBox 
                    x:Name="BrandComboBox" 
                    Header="Brand"
                    MaxWidth="500" 
                    Width="500"
                    Margin="0,0,0,20"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind BrandsList, Mode=OneWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    SelectionChanged="BrandComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                    Loaded="BrandComboBox_Loaded"
                    DropDownOpened="BrandComboBox_DropDownOpened"
                    PlaceholderText="Select brand" />

Code behind
public sealed partial class AddProductPage: Page {

  private readonly ApiService _apiService;

  private readonly ILogger < AddProductPage > _logger;

  private readonly string _apiVersion = "1.0";

  private string _dialogTitle;

  private string _dialogMessage;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private int _currentBrandPage = 1;
  private int _totalBrandPages = 1; // Initialize with 1 or based on your API metadata

  private int _pageSize = 20;

  private bool _isLoadingMoreBrands = false;
  private ObservableCollection < Models.Brand.Brand > BrandsList {
    get;
    set;
  } = new ObservableCollection < Models.Brand.Brand > ();

  /// <summary>
  /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AddProduct"/> class.
  /// </summary>
  public AddProductPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = this;
    _apiService = new ApiService();
    _logger = App.ServiceProvider.GetService < ILogger < AddProductPage >> ();
  }

  private async void BrandComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // Load initial set of brands
    await LoadBrandsAsync(_currentBrandPage, _pageSize);
  }

  // Handle mouse scroll event
  private void BrandComboBoxScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer == null) return;

    // Check if scroll is nearing the bottom
    if (!_isLoadingMoreBrands && scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight * 0.9) {
      LoadMoreBrandsIfNeeded();
    }
  }

  private void BrandComboBoxScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e) {
    var scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight) {
      // Load more items when scrolled to the bottom
      LoadMoreBrandsIfNeeded();
    }
  }

  private async void BrandComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, object e) {
    // Delay to ensure the Popup and its content are fully loaded
    await Task.Delay(100);

    // Get the ItemsPresenter within the ComboBox
    var itemsPresenter = BrandComboBox.FindDescendant < ItemsPresenter > ();
    if (itemsPresenter != null) {
      itemsPresenter.Loaded -= ItemsPresenter_Loaded; // Avoid multiple subscriptions
      itemsPresenter.Loaded += ItemsPresenter_Loaded;
    }
  }

  private void ItemsPresenter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var itemsPresenter = sender as ItemsPresenter;
    var scrollViewer = itemsPresenter?.FindDescendant < ScrollViewer > ();

    if (scrollViewer != null) {
      scrollViewer.ViewChanged += BrandComboBoxScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    }
  }

  private ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject parent) {
    if (parent is ScrollViewer) {
      return (ScrollViewer) parent;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++) {
      var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      var result = FindScrollViewer(child);
      if (result != null) {
        return result;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private async Task LoadBrandsAsync(int page, int pageSize) {
    try {
      string method = $ "api/Brands?page={page}&pageSize={pageSize}";
      var response = await _apiService.GetAsync(method, _apiVersion);

      if (response?.IsSuccessStatusCode == true) {
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var paginatedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < PaginatedResponse < Models.Brand.Brand >> (responseString);
        if (paginatedResponse != null && paginatedResponse.TotalRecords > 1) {
          foreach(var brand in paginatedResponse.Data) {
            BrandsList.Add(brand);
          }
          // Update total pages based on the API response
          _totalBrandPages = (paginatedResponse.TotalRecords + pageSize - 1) / pageSize;
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while loading brands.");

      _dialogTitle = _languageFileContent?.dialog?.error ?? "Error";
      _dialogMessage = _languageFileContent?.message?.error?.unexpectedError ?? "An unexpected error occured.";
      await ErrorDialog.ShowErrorDialogAsync(_dialogTitle, _dialogMessage, this.XamlRoot);
    }
  }

  private async void LoadMoreBrandsIfNeeded() {
    if (_currentBrandPage < _totalBrandPages) {
      _isLoadingMoreBrands = true;
      _currentBrandPage++;
      await LoadBrandsAsync(_currentBrandPage, _pageSize);
      _isLoadingMoreBrands = false;
    }
  }

  private void BrandComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Handle selection change logic here if needed
  }
}

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

"when the user scrolls to the end of the ComboBox load the next 25 and so on." <-- Please do not do this, because combobox drop-downs are incredibly fiddly (as it's easy to accidentally close a combobox drop-down if you misclick or something steals focus, etc): and if someone has a tall-enough display they can simply see all combobox items without any scrolling, so there wouldn't be any scroll-events fired to trigger loading. I recommend yous witch to a listbox that can be "pinned" open with an explicit "Load more" button.

You don't seen to be using ViewModels - why is that?

Strive to avoid writing UIs that have combos that contain more than, say, 20 or 30 items. For more, use a list box with a search facility

Avoid using a list box if: There is a very large number of items. A better choice for long lists are grid view and list view.
